# Randomly generate two colors with a slight difference in shade

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb

I am trying to *randomly* generate a pair of colors with RGB format using JS, which are similar to each other but slightly different in shade.

See in the reference image below, how all 3 "cases" (which would be *randomly* generated) contain two colors, both of which are very similar, but of slightly different shades.

[image: reference image showing desired results]

I tried the following code, but both the colors generated are totally different.

**How** can I have the second color be just slightly different from the first, whilst the pair are generated with random values?

```
ran1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
ran2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
ran3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
ran4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
ran5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
ran6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;

color1 = "rgb(" + ran1 + "," + ran2 + "," + ran3 + ")"; // random color
color2 = "rgb(" + ran4 + "," + ran5 + "," + ran6 + ")"; // probably dissimilar to color1
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Comment: *Ignore the rest coding just provide the random JS functions* That's weird... you talk like my clients, imperative and all, but you didn't asked how much it will cost... Am I free to charge you however I want ?

Comment: Please define _"slight difference in shade"_ in technical terms _e.g._ a few example shades and their different companions (yes I can see the image, but prefer numbers).

Comment: I really dont know what color it shows with a given number but it can be like color1 = rgb(42,9,146) and color2 = rgb(132,99,236). Their is a huge difference in numbers but both colors are quite similar in look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will provide two colors with slightly different shades, but only demonstrates a principle to be expanded; it is not a packaged, perfect, production ready solution.

Basically, it adds to the second color's RGB values, a little bit more than those of the first, if the first's values aren't already too high.

```js
const slightness = 20; // positive for slightly lighter color

const colors = document.querySelectorAll( "div" ),
      color1 = colors[ 0 ],
      color2 = colors[ 1 ];

function shallWe( c ) {
  return c < 236 ? slightness : 0;
}

let ran1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1,
    ran2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1,
    ran3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;

color1.style.background = "rgb(" + ran1 + "," + ran2 + "," + ran3 + ")";
ran1 += shallWe( ran1 );
ran2 += shallWe( ran2 );
ran3 += shallWe( ran3 );
color2.style.background = "rgb(" + ran1 + "," + ran2 + "," + ran3 + ")";
```

```css
div { padding: 2em; }
```

```html
<div></div><div></div>
```